# API Platform Raw Query

Tags: api-platform.com

Anyone knows how to get raw query working in API platform controller/handler,

I am trying to do something like,

```
 $temp_table_query = $this->entityManager->createQuery('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE {temp_validation_code_table} LIKE {validation_code}');
        $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb = $qb->select('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE {$file} INTO TABLE {temp_validation_code_table} (code) SET offer = {$offer}');
```

Trying to load file data into a temporary table for validation before inserting in actual db table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be done using the underlying Doctrine `PDO` abstraction (`Doctrine\DBAL\Connection`), which can be obtained via `$entityManager->getConnection();`.

First however, you need to make sure that the underlying `PDO` connection is configured to allow [LOAD LOCAL INFILE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo-mysql.constants) (by setting `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE` to `true`). This can be done by providing the following Doctrine configuration (in `doctrine.yaml`):

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        #...
        options:
            1001: true # This sets PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE to true
```

*Be warned that allowing LOAD LOCAL INFILE possibly introduces security vulnurabilities.*

Given I have a file named `example.csv` containing the following CSV data:

```
1,"foo"
2,"bar"
3,"baz"
```

I can then insert this data using the Doctrine `PDO` abstraction:

```php
<?php
//...
// Local path to the CSV file
$file = __DIR__ . '/example.csv';
// Obtaining the PDO connection
$connection = $this->entityManager->getConnection();
// Creating the temporary table
$connection->executeStatement('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foobar (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL)');
// Inserting the CSV data
$connection->executeStatement("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE foobar FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
```

Comment: Hey, Jeroen, sorry for my late thank you message, this is exactly what I was looking.
Really appreciate your patience and time spent solving my problem. 
You sir are a professional!